# Scala methods with generic parameter type

Tags: scala, generics, methods

I have been working with Scala for close to a year, but every now and then I come across a piece of code that I don't really understand. This time it is this one. I tried looking into documents on "scala methods with generic parameter type", but I am still confused.

```
def defaultCall[T](featureName : String) (block : => Option[T])(implicit name: String, list:Seq[String]) : Option[T] = 
{
   val value = block match {
     case Some(n) => n match {
        case i : Integer => /*-------Call another method----*/
        case s : String => /*--------Call another method----*/
      }
      case _ => None
 }
```

The method is called using the code shown below :

```
 var exValue = Some(10)
 val intialization = defaultCall[Integer]("StringName"){exValue}
```

What I don't understand in the above described code is the "case" statement in the defaultCall method.

I see that when the exValue has a value and is not empty, the code works as expected. But in case I change the exValue to None, then my code goes into the "case _ = None" condition. I don't understand why this happens since the match done here is against the "variable" which would be either an Integer or a String.

Comment: Don't you mean `var exValue = Some(10)`?

Comment: Just corrected it. Thank you for pointing it out :)

Comment: You initially match against `block`. If `block` is `None`, why won't it go to `case _ = None`?

Comment: Yes, I match it to block. But as far as I understand block=Option[T], and T in this case is a String. Isn't it? Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You are wrong. The match on `case Some(n)` would be acceptable if you send a `Some(...)`, never a `None`. Then, it would try to match the on the value inside the `Some`, which, since you sent `None`, doesn't exist to begin with. It doesn't match on the generic parameter, which is actually impossible since that type doesn't exist in runtime due to type-erasure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What happens here is that when you pass a None it will match on the second case, which "catches" everything that is not an instance of a Some[T]:

```scala
block match {
  case Some(n) => // Will match when you pass an instance of Some[T]
  case _       => // Will match on any other case
}
```

Note that None and Some are two **different** classes that inherit from Option.

Also, the variable match is only done if the first match succeeds, otherwise not. To achieve the type checking in the first match you could do:

```scala
block match {
  case Some(n: Int)    => // do stuff
  case Some(n: String) => // do stuff
  case _               => // Will match on any other case
}
```

Hope that helps